# Very popular answer deleted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, moderation

A number of answers for the question *[Proper Use cases for Android UserManager.isAGoat()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat)* were deleted, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13382561/1209423) by casperOne.  (I'm not sure who is responsible for the  deletions of the other answers which where popular and I feel should have stayed)

I feel that this is an inappropriate action for the moderator to have taken. A moderator may disagree with a post, but it is not grounds for deletion. That is what the up/down vote is for.

Why was this (and other more popular) posts deleted, and is that an appropriate action for a moderator to take?

Comment: I hope you're feeling better. Also, whoa, deleted post with a score of 148.

Comment: If it helps, there are currently 16 deleted answers. 2 self-deleted, the rest deleted by 4 different moderators. (2 of which are actually employees)

Comment: Since when are tabloid-type speculations on-topic on Stack Overflow? That answer you point out isn't more than that.

Comment: BTW, you *believe* that I'm abusing my moderator (no quotes, I *am* a moderator) status.  From the votes on this meta post, it seems there are those that don't entirely agree with that statement.

Comment: I have edited the post to attempt to avoid closure as "not constructive".  If you feel that the edit is not in line with your underlying question, please edit the post accordingly.  I feel that there is a valid question here, but the use of a few "harsh" words were not constructive.

Comment: were you arguing that all the other deletions were justified and that only the one by casperOne was problematic? The edit by @Servy seems to suggest so and I'm not entirely sure that is what you intended to say.

Comment: Reddit kids.  Pah.

Comment: @Bart I agree it's not 100% clear.  I assumed that `"not sure who is responsible for the other deletions of answers that where just fine"` meant that he didn't have a problem with the deletion of the other answers to this question.  I assumed that the plural references to answers being incorrectly deleted was that he felt this is a more broad problem happening in other questions besides this one, and that this is one example.  I essentially changed it to be [tag:specific-question].

Comment: @Servy Yeah, the OP might have meant that. It's not a big deal, so let's wait for some feedback/confirmation there. :)

Comment: I linked to my answer in that question because I cannot see the *other* deleted answers. I have a problem with so many HIGHLY voted answers, which had no issues (answered the question) where deleted. Mine was deleted; its the only 'deleted' answer I could see. Not a mod. Edit: -13 for this question so far. Mods are up tight today.

Comment: @PenguinCoder Could you drop the non-constructive attitude? -13 might easily be caused by simple user disagreement. No mods need to be involved there. We tried to edit your question into something a bit more constructive. It's always better to try to somewhat neutrally address a problem. Even if you're terribly upset. It will get you a far better response.

Comment: @bart I attempt previously, and on the question stated/referenced in my above question to 'play nice'. I did nothing wrong and was polite at that time. Strike the last sentence from the above comment, but my issue still lies with moderators (or high rep users who 50 pts doesn't matter to them) abusing certain privileges they've gained. That frustration crosses over into text, although doesn't change the point of what I am trying to say.

Comment: @PenguinCoder I just find it a shame that your point (which you might have) possibly gets drowned in downvotes and close votes when a simple change of tone might have (partially) prevented it. But of course I can only speculate on the reason for those votes.

Answer (score 15):

The question in question is currently headlining on multiple social link sharing sites.  The actions of the moderators seem to be in line with making the discussion *constructive* and in line with the actual question being asked.

Many of the deleted answers did not actually attempt to *answer* the question about what the function does and how it should be used, even the ones *speculating* about the relationship between Android goats and Chrome goats.  (Honestly, IMO, the [top-rated one about that speculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375746/168868) is OK, especially given the source code citation...)

Comment: Man, 63k views in 10 hours... Is that a new record?

Comment: I agree that the top-rated answer should not have been deleted. Showing that it's a reference to an existing joke is the strongest way to prove that it is meant as a joke. That's more informative than the top non-deleted answer, which tries to rationalize a use for it, even though it's probably not meant to be used. (edit: I've raised a flag.)

Comment: @JeremyBanks The question, however, is not "what is the meaning behind this joke" (which is off topic, btw) it is "what are valid use cases for this" which the top voted answer *does not answer* and therefore, "Not An Answer" and deleted as such.

Comment: @casperOne If "doesn't answer the exact question" is now criteria for deletion, I have quite a backlog of old answers for you to delete. I don't think people would respond favourably, however.

Comment: @casperOne: Convert to comm— oh wait, 500 character limit.

Comment: @casperOne Not to disagree with you, but your argument seems to run counter to policy that "no it's not possible" is a valid answer. Here the question is, "what are the ...". The answer is, "there are none".

Comment: Wait wait wait wait, did you add an extra sentence to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat/13385236#13385236) to make it an answer? I'm not entirely sure putting words in other people's mouths is the best idea... I'd have prompted the user with a comment instead at most.

Comment: @Mysticial The question is not "is this possible" the question is "when should I use this".  As you see from the currently undeleted top rated answer, it attempts to show a valid use case.

Comment: @Mysticial: I disagree on this count. The top-voted deleted answer doesn't even talk about Android or the method in question. It's doesn't say "there are no use cases" or anything else than say it probably has something to do with an easter egg on another Google product.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Within reason, of course.  If you answer the fundamental question, but do it in a way that someone wasn't expecting, then those are legitimate answers.  However, if you're answering "what color are oranges" with "apples are red", those answers have to go.  Feel free to flag those for deletion.

Comment: @casperOne That seems to go against the "mods don't judge the technical accuracy of an answer" kind of flag rejections. Which, as you know, are often discussed here by users who are surprised that an obviously wrong answer is not handled by mods...

Comment: @Mat Fair enough. But when I read it, "there are no use cases" was implied. Perhaps it could have been made more clear.

Comment: @Bart Describing why an API exists isn't about the technical voracity of an answer.  Look at the API page or the developer blog for that.  The question is "what are valid use cases".  I'm not judging whether or not the use case is accurate.  I can't, as no use case was presented in that answer.

Comment: @Bart The mod is not making any critique of whether the response is correct or not.  The answer may be correct or it might not be.  Regardless of whether or not it's correct, it doesn't even *attempt* to answer the question, so it's validity is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Let's take the 30K ft view as well.  There are almost 70K views on this question *on the day it was asked and before the day is over*.  Do we want, as a community when these questions are seen by the outside to present crap, or something that's actually useful?  I'm trying to make it useful.  Telling the history or the reasoning behind why a joke was made isn't useful or helpful.  The answers that are left, *are*, and that's what we want people to see when they look at us.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, I did indeed add the sentence to that answer to try and add additional substance, because it was the best possible answer of those that, at the time, were not deleted.  While you're right that normally it's best to poke and prod in a comment, given the level of (no offense intended) obsessive pickyness going on, I felt it'd be easier just to alter the answer directly.

Comment: @casperOne Quote: *Telling the history or the reasoning behind why a joke was made isn't useful or helpful.* I utterly, 100% completely, disagree with you. The difference is; I can't delete your incorrect answer or comment with wanton disregard.

Comment: @PenguinCoder I'm not sure what your point is.  In my answer, I at least answered your question.  Here's the thing, if you have issue with that answer then you should also be taking the issue up with the other moderators, users, and SE employees that have deleted *other* answers that say the *same exact thing* as the deleted answer you've pointed out.  This wasn't a personal bias against the question or answer, it's following what was clearly done before on that question to make the entire post live up to Stack Overflow's quality guidelines.

Comment: @PenguinCoder I could also give you the entire list of issues as to why any war (with a decisive victor) was fought, but it doesn't answer the question "who won the war".  The answer, fundamentally, *is to the wrong question*, a question that would be off topic by Stack Overflow standards.  If you *really* want *that* question to be answered, we can undelete everything, but then we'd close it immediately afterwards.

Comment: @casperOne You're the mod. Do what you want.

Comment: @PenguinCoder Again, not sure what the purpose of your last comment is.  We're trying to keep the question constructive, you've come to meta in an unconstructive way and are lobbing accusations around which usually doesn't help with the collective goal of increasing quality on the site.

Answer (score 5):

The answer that you reference *does not answer the question*.  The question, at a fundamental level is:

> What are proper use cases for X?

The top voted answer you refer to says:

> X is visible here and Y, related to X is visible here

That said, anything that doesn't answer the question *as asked* will be deleted (as a number of other moderators, people who answered the question, and SE employees have *already* done).

It's the only way to keep the question remotely constructive and *on topic* for the site.

If you really want to know ideas as to *why* the API is named that and accept those answers, then it makes the question *off topic* for Stack Overflow.

Also, to the argument and the existing flags on the answer saying it is a joke and this is the reason for the joke, there's nothing in the actual question (or any revision of the question) indicating that the person *didn't* know it was a joke.

If anything, the question itself indicates that they *know* it's a joke, given that they're asking for *valid* uses of the API.

Comment: It was not immediately obvious to me whether this is a joke name for a useful method, or a joke method with no use. The post giving a contrived use misses the point (a "proper" use case) completely. Elaborating on the "yes, it's a joke" point is more useful as an answer, insofar as anything relating to that question is useful.

Comment: @McCannot From the initial revision "Does anyone know how and when should this be used?".  Because it's a joke doesn't mean it *shouldn't* be used.  If there's a legitimate use for it, then we'd like to see it.  If there's not, then we'd like to see it (but it's very difficult to prove that point, of course, but we wouldn't delete it if it tried very hard to elaborate as to why that's their position).  But that answer doesn't even give one of those positions.  It simply says "this was a joke and why".

Comment: On the contrary, being a joke is an *excellent* reason to not use a method. And I don't dispute the utility of the deleted answer, I dispute that it was *less useful* than the remaining high-voted answer or, for that matter, the question. I should note that, as a card-carrying member of the No Fun Allowed Club I've already voted to close the question and would be happy to see it deleted as well.

Comment: @McCannot If the answer stated that belief that it's a joke and it should *not* be used, then it would not have been deleted.  However, that's not the case and doing so now would be a destructive edit.  If you really want to see that, then @ the user and ask him to edit his question to reflect his position (if it is his position) and then we can undelete it.  It's not that I don't trust the editing of SO right now, but at this point, there are too many cooks in the kitchen on this, might as well let the original chef handle the recipe and then take it from there.

Comment: It really, *really* stretches the limits of plausibility to see "it's a joke" as not implying "it has no practical use". If we accept your premise that the questioner knows the method is a joke, then there's nothing useful to answer and the whole question should be NARQ'd with extreme prejudice. Unfortunately I'm out of delete votes today and now the question has been re-opened anyway. *Sigh.*

Comment: @McCannot Why is saying "I know this wasn't meant to have any practical usage, but I was wondering if there *are* practical usages" implausible?  There are practical uses for impractical things all the time.  There's no reason that it can't be that way in code either, and the third highest voted answer (as of this writing) is an attempt to answer the question legitimately.