# How to discourage joke questions

Tags: discussion, humor

The recent goat example in my opinion is an example of a question that, though properly formatted, should have been blocked much earlier.

I know the question in some manner has been beneficial to the Stack Overflow community but the question and some of the answers could be perceived as just a way to garner easy rep.

The question however is a properly formatted API question but the answer is in the comments in the original question. Its clearly a joke API method and therefore the API has no valid use.

There also appears to be some edit waring going on over the question with statuses changing over time and at least two people complaining about moderation.

I would like for the moderation to even be stricter on these questions, possibly putting into a community-wiki as soon as it appeared to be going viral and protected earlier.

**Ref**

[Proper use cases for Android UserManager.isUserAGoat()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat)

[How can we encourage down-voting over deletion on answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155761/how-can-we-encourage-down-voting-over-deletion-on-answers)

Comment: This "problem" is somewhat fundamental to everything that is funny - regardless of whether it's a real question or not. In this case, I do think it's a real question that happens to be funny.

Comment: I have to disagree with you - the question is fine, even if the API method is a joke. It is indeed part of the API and is even documented, so someone is fully justified to ask about it.

Comment: I didn't vote for deletion

Comment: `"Its clearly a joke API method and therefore the api has no valid use."` Then it must have been surprising to you to see answers that contained valid uses for this "joke" method, yes?  Seems like it added value to me.

Comment: I didn't vote for deletion but what I do think is at least 607*5 rep points would be given (okay didn't take into account the cap) it just feels like easy rep gain. Award the OP with 50 points and none of the joke answers. Community wiki the whole lot. The traffic is useful and it's actually nice to see some light hearted stuff but not at the expense of edit wars.  Compare to move turtle at least that had some value over an api who's method is clearly a joke and the only real answer is it shouldn't be used. That was meant to be my earlier comment.

Comment: @Servy "Does anyone know how and when this should be used?" has not been answered by the answers. The one semi-usefull answer is how to avoid a piece of code running without compiler warnings.

Comment: @Wes And you'll note that most of the answers that didn't actually answer the question were deleted; the system works!  As for the rep; consider the rep cap.  That'll make almost all of that go away.

Comment: If that question hangs arround it will continue to gather rep? My understanding of the rep cap is that its a cap per user per day. Not a cap per question/answer per day. And look at people complaining about the moderation on the deleted answers.

Comment: @Wes: *So what* if it gathers rep? Is it important that rep is an accurate measurement of something? Because it's not. Some people get easy rep by asking the right question in the right place at the right time. Some people don't. It happens. *I'd personally just move on*.

Comment: Clearly, you've never received a phone call from a goat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see the problem. This is a legitimate question. There's an API function. The documentation for it is unclear. What does it do and when should you use it? That's a perfectly valid Stack Overflow question.

It doesn't represent any real research effort, yes (as it's pretty obvious that the API function has no real value). So feel free to downvote it. However, that doesn't mean it should be closed, nor does it mean that it should be removed.

Your problem isn't that this question exists. *Your* problem is that it got 600+ upvotes in a day or two. As you say:

> I didn't vote for deletion but what I do think is at least 607*5 rep points would be given (okay didn't take into account the cap) it just feels like easy rep gain.

So what if it's easy rep gain? If that bothers you, then you seem to have succumbed to the fantasy that reputation is a measure of worth. It isn't. It is, *at best*, an order-of-magnitude approximation.

Some people win the rep lottery. This guy did. It happens. It's not hurting you, and it's not negatively impacting the site. It may not be a question that's worth 600+ upvotes, but that's the nature of the Internet. Not everyone agrees with you.

Accept it and move on.

Comment: +1 for a well formulated answer

Comment: And if anything, finding such a funny question to ask is not an easy task in itself. So I can't call it "easy rep". You really have to just randomly come across that API function. And then it has to strike your mind that it might be worth posting on SO.

Comment: `It doesn't represent any real research effort` + `the fantasy that reputation is a measure of worth. It isn't. It is, at best, an order-of-magnitude approximation.` + `It may not be a question that's worth 600+ upvotes, but that's the nature of the Internet.` LOL there is so much wrong with this answer even though I agree with it. The flaws of SO staring at you right in the face @_@

Comment: @phwd: Nobody ever claimed SO didn't have flaws. But it's still better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

How about we let people ask the questions they want to ask and let the community vote and regulate from there instead?

We need to stop wishing for the system and for moderators to handle every little detail of the site for us. We should all be capable of thinking for ourselves and using the tools within the system to handle these issues on our own.