# How much reputation did I lost downvoting bad answers?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

How could I know how much answers did I downvote? Are there some queries to get this information?

It is important because I'm not sure how much downvotes can I cast.

**Edit:**

As @Servy notes

> the number of downvoted answers won't be the same as the amount of rep lost from downvotes

so, actually, I want to know only how much rep I lost. But if you suggest way to get both this values to compare it with each other - it can be pretty useful too.

Comment: Note that the number of downvoted answers won't be the same as the amount of rep lost from downvotes if you ever hit the rep cap after downvoting answers.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter: 233 is the number of answer OP voted on (up or down). The breakdown isn't public afaik.

Comment: @Mat sigh yep you're right, although there is the ?tab=votes&sort=downvote on the profile but that includes Questions and answers

Comment: Well, the OP can count every single one by looking through the pages on his reputation tab, so it's *possible*.  I know of no place to get the aggregated data without counting them one by one.

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter That should also include downvotes on questions, no?

Comment: You can visit http://stackoverflow.com/reputation, and count the number of `(-1)`s. To get the real value, also take into account the `(1)`s (from undownvoting / deleting answer).

Comment: "lost" doesn't feel like the right word here, I would say _invested_. [Quoting self](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155762/165773 "from here"), '...I downvote quite frequently and rep points I loose for doing this feel like an "investment" into site quality; pretty rewarding.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your reputation audit for that. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, and count the lines with vote type 3 and `(-1)` in the reputation part. (Those with `(-2)` are your answers that received a downvote.)

This won't contain downvotes you've cast on answers that have since been deleted. And there might be quirks with days you've hit the reputation cap on (you'll get entries with `[-1]` instead there if you downvoted after having hit the cap, so still pretty usable).

Comment: I think we can save it to a text file and then do some python/bash/perl/ruby scripting to find out the actual rep lost due to downvoting answers... Does it sound doable?

Comment: Of course. You could do it in Javascript from your browser too, if you like that. Could probably do some sort of plugin/addon with great visualization of your rep history and publish it on http://stackapps.com/. (I'm not interested at all in doing this though.)